# Vue form not sending data in request

Tags: php, ajax, vuejs2

I have a form in one component, and I am trying to send data on submit with Ajax request:

```
          <form>
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input is-large" type="email" v-model="email" required>
              <label>E-post</label>
            </div>
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input is-large" type="password" v-model="password" required>
              <label>Passord</label>
            </div>
            <div @click="save" type="submit" class="button hero-button is-medium is-primary">
              Logg in
            </div>
          </form>
```

This is the method for post request, I am using axios library for Ajax requests:

```
methods: {
      save() {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('email', this.email);
        form.append('password', this.password);

        this.$backend.post('/user/login', form, {
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('success');
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
      }
    }
```

But, when I check on the backend side, built with laravel, I get an empty request:

> {"request":[]}

This is the function in the controller on the backend side:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        //testing $request object
        return ['request' => $request->all()];            

        $authenticatedUser = $this->authenticate($request->email, $request->password);

        if (!$authenticatedUser) {

            $remoteAuthenticated = $this->checkWplUser($request->email, $request->password);
            if (!$remoteAuthenticated) {

                return $this->response->errorUnauthorized();
            }
        }
        return $this->issueToken($request->email, $request->password);
        //return $this->returnUserResponse();
    }
```

This is how the request header looks like:

[image]
How can I fix this?

Comment: what error you are getting  ?

Comment: are you passing the values correctly to your php page? can you post a picture of your xhr request header?

Comment: just return `return dd($request->all());` and check network tab in browser ?

Comment: yes, I get an empty object for ```$request->all()```